# How to retrieve a record from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i'm new to android programming and i have created a sample app which allows the user to get data from the database. however its not displaying the data, it doesn't have any error message its just not displaying it. database is confirmed that there is data. please check my code maybe i forgot something here. thanks

```
public void onClick(View arg){
    name = txtNameS.getText().toString();
    if(arg.getId()==R.id.btnfortune){
            searchRecord(count);
            lblmessageS1.setText(name); // this is just for me to check     if it will be displayed and it is.
            lblmessageS2.setText(message);
    }

 }



 public void searchRecord(int count) throws SQLException {
    Cursor rsCursor;

    String [] rsFields = {"mesNum","Message"};

   rsCursor = dbM.dbase.query("MessageFile", rsFields, "mesNum = " + count, null, null, null, null, null);
    rsCursor.moveToFirst();

    if (rsCursor.isAfterLast()==false){

        message = rsCursor.getString(1);
    }

    rsCursor.close();
 }
```

by the way count is initialized as 1. and there are 10 records in the database. and there are 2 columns in the database the mesNum and Message, what i want is to display only the message column.

Comment: why you just don't debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add only one column name in your array

```
String [] rsFields = {"Message"};

    cursor = dbM.dbase.query(true,"MessageFile", rsFields, "yourcolumn= "+count, null, null, null, null, null);

while( cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext() ) 
{
  cursor.getString(0);
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: my pleasure :).. and dont call me sir.. its ok :)

Answer (score 1):

```
      // SQLiteDatabase sqldb
     Cursor rsCursor= sqldb.rawQuery("your query", null);
     if (rsCursor!= null) {
            if (rsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                     // do here for get data   message = rsCursor.getString(1);
                   }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Comment: sir i will get some error if i use this code fragment, i'll get a fatal exception